# Stretch divs based on wrapper AND on window positions without JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

The following image will be helpful.

Consider a traditional centered wrapper with max-width.

Then wrapper has 2 columns using 40% and 60% of the wrapper respectively (random number that isn't 50%).

Is there a way to stretch the divs outter limit to match the window borders without Javascript - while the inner limits respect the wrapper reference?

[image: divs stratching]

This unfortunatelly doesn't work:

```
#div1{
    left: 0vw;
    right: 40%; /*of .wrapper */
}

#div2{
    left: 40%; /*of .wrapper */
    right: 100vw;
}
```

Solution with JS (poorly written): https://jsfiddle.net/sirojuntle/ktvap86c/12/

The idea is to make smaller desktop layout looks better in larger screens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your wrapper is `position: relative;` half your job is already done.  Even with `position: absolute;` your divs still take the wrapper as their parent co-ordinates.

With that in mind, it's easier than you think.

```
.div1{
right: 60%; /* is 40% from the left, like your picture */
left: calc(50% - 50vw)
}
.div2{
left: 40%;
right: calc(50% - 50vw)
}
```

Comment: Very clever solution! It is pretty much what I was trying to do from the begining, but I have to remark the other guy solution is amazin too. Thank you!

Comment: jsfiddle for future reference: https://jsfiddle.net/sirojuntle/otdh3bjm/21/

Comment: Thanks!  Pretty sure the math works out the same for both solutions, but mine has negative position while Leo's has negative margin.  Mine determines the width based on the sides, Leo's has one side determined by the width lol.
Just keep in mind though that both solutions work because your parent is centred.  If you ever decide to change that you'll need to reassess this code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with negative margin

```
.wrapper {
  --m: min(0px, (800px - 100vw)/2);
}
.row1 {
  width: calc(40% - var(--m));
  margin-left: var(--m);
}
.row2 {
  width: calc(60% - var(--m));
  margin-right: var(--m);
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Full code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  --m: min(0px, (800px - 100vw)/2);
  
  border: 3px solid pink;
  max-width: 800px;
  background-size: 10%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #0000 5%);
  margin:auto;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: calc(40% - var(--m));
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: var(--m);
}

.row2 {
  background-color: darkred;
  width: calc(60% - var(--m));
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: var(--m);
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row1" id="ref">
      There is a way to stretch this with CSS?
    </div>
    <div class="row2" id="ref2">
      And that?
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm voting for the other guy answer because it solves the thing the way I was wishing it could be solved, but I'm absolutely impressed that your solution basically converts my javascript logic to plain css. I was not even aware this was possible, thank you for the lesson!

Comment: jsfiddle for future reference: https://jsfiddle.net/sirojuntle/otdh3bjm/19/

Comment: I learnt something here too.  Didn't know "min" was a thing!  My calc started out fairly similar (with the 800px) but I was going to suggest to add a breakpoint for screen widths under that before I realised it wasn't needed.